# How to run Gem5 simulator in fs mode without cache?

Tags: caching, gem5

I am able to run gem5 in fs mode , but now i want to remove cache from the system. So what changes i need to do in gem5/configs/example/fs.py file to remove cache and run successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Caches are disabled by default, use `--caches --l2cache` to enable them**

Then the question comes down to how to observe if caches are on or off.

I've tried the following methods:

- look into `m5out/config.ini`.

  That file contains a representation of the system configuration as a tree.

  The following entries are only present if we pass the cache flags:

  ```
  [system]
  children=l2

  [system.cpu]
  children=dcache icache
  ```
- Run some benchmarks with and without caches, and notice that they are slower without caches.

  Here are some examples: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/f3503b4cc810556df3c736d0a147cc54e05efc83#gem5-cache-size
- Look into the Linux kernel special file systems like `/sys`.

  Doesn't work currently unfortunately: [Why doesn't the Linux kernel see the cache sizes in the gem5 emulator in full system mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49008792/why-doesnt-the-linux-kernel-see-the-cache-sizes-in-the-gem5-emulator-in-full-sy)

**Caches don't make much difference for the default ARM `--cpu-type=AtomicSimpleCPU`**

You likely want to use `--cpu-type=HPI`

HPI is more detailed, which makes the simulation slower.

TODO understand AtomicSimpleCPU in more detail, and why caches don't matter there.

TODO check out for X86 `DerivO3CPU` vs `AtomicSimpleCPU`. Blocked on: https://github.com/cirosantilli-work/gem5-issues/issues/2